# Error while installing TestNG in eclipse neon

Tags: eclipse-plugin, testng.xml

I am trying to install testNG in eclipse and getting the below erro

Unable to read repository at https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/6.14.3/content.xml. Unable to read repository at https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/6.14.3/content.xml.

Comment: Eclipse Neon is 15 releases and more than 5 years behind. Please make sure all software used is up to date before asking. There is a separate Stack Exchange for [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The only site that seems to be working is `https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/` but that only has the current 7.4.0